# Balanced Array partitioning with max weight constraint

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have found a couple of known partitioning problems, but none seems to quite fit the following issue.

**Problem:**

You have an array *A* with *N* positive integers and you need to divide it into *M* contiguous segments. There is a given *limit* that the sum of each segment must not exceed, and every integer *n* in *A <= limit*. I want to find a minimum number of segments that fulfill the limit condition. Additionally the segments should be well balanced, such that the difference between all the segments sums is minimized.

**Example:**

```
A = { 2, 3, 5, 5 }, limit = 6

solution => M=3, partitions={2,3},{5},{5}

A = { 3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2 }, limit = 12

solution => M=4, partitions={3,3,3},{4,4},{4,4},{4,2,2,2}
```

In the second example one could also find M=4 segments with a partitioning of
{3,3,3},{4,4,4},{4,4,2,2},{2}, but the difference of the sum of all segments is larger than in the previous solution.

Is this a known problem and does a solution with a small complexity exist (or any approximations if the cost of the optimal solution is too high)?

**Edit:** Finding a minimal amount of segments has the priority. Out of all minimal M solutions, I want to find the most balanced one (or one close to it)

Comment: You want to minimise two things. Which one has precedence, or is there a trade-off between the two?

Comment: "I want to find a minimum number of segments that fulfill the limit condition." -- then just maintain a running total for the current segment, and start a new segment as soon as adding the next item would cause the current segment to exceed *limit*.  This addresses one of your two optimality criteria; as @trincot said, you need to decide which one you actually want to minimise.

Comment: A minimal amount of segments has the priority. The balancing is an additional criteria.  So out of all minimal segments, i want to have the most balanced solution. A running total does not work in this case, as the remark on the second example demonstrates. A simple idea was to calculate a minimal M with a running total, calculate a mean = (total weight of A) / M and by reverse iteration form new segments that come close to  the mean (with maybe some optimizations). But it does look like a problem to me that might have been solved already?

Comment: Seems to be a one dimensional cutting stock problem with the extra requirement of a balanced solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: This is an NP-hard problem reducible to knapsack problem. With exponential complexity (brute force) I'm sorry to say. You could do some pruning given that you have that threshold, but still.